# Is unauthenticated access to AWS Location 'Places' API possible?

Tags: amazon-web-services, geocoding

I'm just getting started with Amazon Location Services, which I realise has only been recently released. I've created my first map, and can access it fine as an unauthenticated user. However, I'm trying to now add geocoding functionality, but it's not clear to me how to grant unauthenticated access to the 'places' API (or whether it is even possible). The documentation explicitly covers granting unauthenticated access to maps, but it is silent on this topic for places.

I have tried a simple POST to https://places.geo.eu-west-1.amazonaws.com/places/v0/indexes//search/text, but I get back an HTTP 403 response.

To be clear, the API I'm trying to access as an unauthenticated user is discussed here: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/location/latest/developerguide/search-place-index-geocode.html

Is unauthenticated access possible to the 'Places API' from AWS Location services?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For anyone reading this in the future, I eventually got this working, but man it was painful! I know Amazon Location is new, but the documentation is quite poor.

Firstly, you need to create an unauthenticated identity pool that can access the 'places' resource. This is documented for the maps on https://docs.aws.amazon.com/location/latest/developerguide/tutorial-mapbox.html, but there is no similar documentation for the Places API.

I created a single identity pool covering maps and places with this:

```
{
  "Version": "2012-10-17",
  "Statement": [
    {
      "Sid": "MapsReadOnly",
      "Effect": "Allow",
      "Action": [
        "geo:GetMapStyleDescriptor",
        "geo:GetMapGlyphs",
        "geo:GetMapSprites",
        "geo:GetMapTile"
      ],
      "Resource": "arn:aws:geo:eu-west-1:XXXXXXXXXX:map/mapdemo"
    },
    {
      "Sid": "PlacesReadOnly",
      "Effect": "Allow",
      "Action": [
        "geo:SearchPlaceIndex*"
      ],
      "Resource": "arn:aws:geo:eu-west-1:XXXXXXXXX:place-index/placedemo"
    }
  ]
}
```

This alone isn't enough. You need to sign the HTTP requests, using Amazon's cognito library. Again, an example of how to do this for their maps is given in the transformRequest function in https://docs.aws.amazon.com/location/latest/developerguide/tutorial-mapbox-gl-js.html, but there's no such thing for the Places API.

You might think they'd be the same, but you'd be wrong. Because the 'places' requests are POSTs, the signing mechanism is different (it needs to sign the URL, the method and the request body). So the updated transformRequest function looks like this:

```
  function transformRequest(url, resourceType, body) {
    if (resourceType === "Style" && !url.includes("://")) {
      // resolve to an AWS URL
      url = `https://maps.geo.${AWS.config.region}.amazonaws.com/maps/v0/maps/${url}/style-descriptor`;
    }

    if (url.includes("amazonaws.com")) {
      // There's two types of Amazon requests at play here. Tile requests are GET, but place requests
      // (geocoding) are POSTs. When doing a POST request, you need to pass up the POST verb, _and_ the
      // POST body to the AWS request signer.
      return {
        url: Signer.signUrl({
          url: url,
          method: url.includes("places.geo") ? "POST" : "GET",
          body: url.includes("places.geo") ? body : undefined
        },
        {
          access_key: credentials.accessKeyId,
          secret_key: credentials.secretAccessKey,
          session_token: credentials.sessionToken,
        }),
      };
    }
```

Once you've done all this, you still have to get a geocoding client library working on the frontend. I ended up modifying the Mapbox GL Geocoder. The Mapbox GL Geocoder already supports an 'externalGeocoder' option, which can be used to plugin to AWS's Places API.

It would be nice if Amazon included an example of how to use the Places API on the client side, like they do with the maps.